# dissmissing keyboard in view with tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

I am using the tabview and it works fine but if i add the code for dismissing the keyboard by clicking anywhere the tabbar stops working but all the other buttons work. here is the code that I used to dismiss the keyboard:

```
extension UIViewController {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the best way to handle this, but without experiementing, this seems to be the only foolproof method I know of. This will create an invisible view that recognizes a click and deletes itself on click.

```
class ThisViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource {

    var tapView: ClickThroughView?

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        tapView = ClickThroughView(frame: view.frame)
        tapView?.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(tapView!)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(tapView!)
    }

    func keyboardWillHide() {
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
}

extension ThisViewController: HandleViewTapDelegate {
    func handleTap() {

        //code on tap not on keyboard
        view.endEditing(true)

        tapView?.removeFromSuperview()
        tapView = nil
    }
}

protocol HandleViewTapDelegate {
    func handleTap()
}

class ClickThroughView: UIView {
    var delegate: HandleViewTapDelegate?

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        delegate?.handleTap()
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it putting a button on the background and making the action for that button call `view.endEditing(true)`

It is not the prettiest fix but it works